# If - else statement not working in Android

Tags: android, if-statement, android-asynctask

So I have my class extending AppCompatActivity. On button press I'm creating new Async task for internet connection passing reference to this class, and at the end of doInBackground I call function in my class.

```
private LoginAct act;
```

[...]

```
@Override
protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {
    try
    {
        //LOGIN into account or create new one - returns id (as string str)
        int id = Integer.parseInt(str.toString());
        System.out.println(id);
        //id is fine
        act.postexecute(id);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return "ERROR: " + e.getMessage();
    }
    return null;
}
```

as for now, everything is fine, but than postexecute method not work as it's suppsed to:

```
public void postexecute(int id)
{
    //it works fine here
    if(id == 0)
    {
        System.out.println("postexecuting!");
        edPas.setError("Nickname and password don't match!");
        loadBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Less postexecuting!");
        onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Problem is, no matter what id input is, neither *if* or *else* statements prop. I have no idea, what the problem could be, and all questions I've seen around weren't even close to my problem...

Comment: you cannot update the UI from a backgroud thread

Comment: How could I menage my UI to do something after async task does his thing?

Comment: Could you please edit your original post to include your full AsyncTask code.

Comment: onPostExecute is where you do stuff for the UI in your AsyncTask

Comment: Moving 'act.postexecute(id);' to onPostExecute worked fine, thanks. But I'm still wondering, why the function is called, and System.out that was in place of "//it works fine here" worked, but than if statement wasn't working...

Answer (score 0):

The code is fine. Although, you are not allowed to make make changes on the GUI from there.

Answer (score 0):

You should not change the UI from some other thread. Either use runOnUiThread of activity or use onPostExecute() of AsyncTask.

Change return type for doInBackground() to int.

```
@Override
protected int doInBackground(Object[] params) {
int id = some_default_value;
try
{
    //LOGIN into account or create new one - returns id (as string str)
    id = Integer.parseInt(str.toString());
    System.out.println(id);
    //id is fine
    //act.postexecute(id);
} catch (Exception e) {

}
return id;
}
```

Now implement onPostExecute() of AsyncTask.

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(int id) {
        super.onPostExecute(id);
        //it works fine here
        if(id == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("postexecuting!");
            edPas.setError("Nickname and password don't match!");
            loadBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Less postexecuting!");
            onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The AsyncTask already gives you a method called `onPostExecute()` for you to handle the result from your task, you don't need to implement a method for it as you can not change the UI during `doInBackGround()`.

I don't know how your code is, but in this case you could define a class variable on the top of your class

```
private int id;
```

in your `doInBackground` save it:

```
@Override
protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {
try
{
    //LOGIN into account or create new one - returns id (as string str)
    id = Integer.parseInt(str.toString());
    System.out.println(id);
} catch (Exception e) {
    return "ERROR: " + e.getMessage();
}
return null;
}
```

And after that, `onPostExecute()`:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(typeYouDefinedAsArgument myArgument){
    super.onPostExecute(myArgument);
    if(id == 0)
{
    System.out.println("postexecuting!");
    edPas.setError("Nickname and password don't match!");
    loadBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
else
{
    System.out.println("Less postexecuting!");
    onBackPressed();
}
```